# Startup sounds do not work on kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, startup, 22.04

I have tried to change my startup sound on Kubuntu 22.04 but it does not work, it doesnt play anything, Ive used the default and a custom one and neither work (other system sounds do work though), is there a solution?

Comment: I have the same issue.